# FBGrab gives a black .png image

Tags: linux, framebuffer

I am using fbgrab to take a screenshot of my framebuffer. When I run fbdev as `sudo fbdev capture.png` it saves the file but when I open the image it is just a fully black image. I have also tried dumping the framebuffer with `cat /dev/fb0 > fbdump` with the same blackscreen when opening it in a RAW image viewer. Does anyone know why this is happening? Something helpful I get at the shell when running fbgrab is `pnmtopng: 1 colors found`. I am assuming this means exactly what it sounds like and it is only finding a single color? Another tool I tried was a perl script that read the RAW data and converted it into a .png. I ended up getting the same result. I am on a 64bit ZorinOS install with a 1366x768 screen. I do recall this happening in Pop!_OS and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I created this question before I had much technical experience with the interior workings of Linux, but know that I do, I will share with people who may also be having this issue:

The main reason is that Xorg and Wayland do not use the Framebuffer. In Xorg, you must set "Use Framebuffer" in the configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use fbgrab (which version) or the wrapper to fbcat which is in debian/ubuntu derivatives?

If you are indeed using fbgrab, try -a, which ignores the alpha plane, available in newer versions of fbgrab.

If that does not solve you problem, please provide output of fbgrab -v.